# Memory footprint optimalization vs performance

Tags: c, string, memory, c99

I've got concern about memory footprint of my C99 application which loads a lot of strings. I have got upper bound for string length and I basically do something like this (this statements are in loop):

```
char* input = (char*)malloc(sizeof (char)* MAX_CHAR_INPUT_SIZE);
scanf_s("%s", input, MAX_CHAR_INPUT_SIZE);
```

As you can see if string provided by user is small a lot of memory is wasted. My only idea is to copy that string, after read, to well sized block of memory and then free the bigger one. Is this good approach? (I know it will be O(N)).

Also could someone explain to me how this is solved in higher-level languages? (for example C#'s Console.Read())

Comment: in other languages is really common to consider the type for the string associated to a variable as an instance with an immutable state, which means that if the user needs to modify the state ( edit the string or associate a different one with the given variable ) of the string, a new string is created ( the logic behind the creation of the new string obviously depends on what the user is doing ) and attached to the label; this is pretty much the way it happens.

Comment: Other languages that have mutable strings (e.g. StringBuilder, which is sometimes used for efficiency) will start with a small size and then increase it if necessary.

Comment: in c++ strings are mutable and supposedly grow exponantially by a factor of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it in a loop then you can read it into a temporary before allocating the memory for the final string:

```
char input[MAX_CHAR_INPUT_SIZE];

scanf_s("%s", input, sizeof input);

size_t input_size = strlen(input) + 1;
char *input_final = malloc(input_size);
memcpy(input_final, input, input_size);
```

This way you still only have one call to `malloc()` per string, but allocate the exact right size each time.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should consider is that malloc() is a very expensive function as compared to memcpy(), especially when concurrency is concerned. One of the more common strategies in the high performance programs is to actually pre-allocate as much buffer memory as possible in thread local storage and then actually copy data (strings included) between these buffers to minimize the amount of shared state which needs to be protected.

This works well because CPUs have plenty of cheap computational resource and are optimized to move data around efficiently. This is opposed to data access synchronization scenarios, which, on modern systems are very complex (multiple cores with multi-level cache hierarchies involved) and thus slow.

Same works for "managed memory" environments, such as JVM and CLR (with whatever languages). Check out this article on high performance Java trading system (the approach is the same: preallocate memory then copy extensively to minimize shared state): http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html

And, as always, one must not be to zealous with any programming technique and pattern. It is easy to overdue the copying to such an extent as to make the perfectly good programs unbelievably slow (or to consume too much memory needlessly). Extensive benchmarking is an absolute imperative.